# Deduce return type of function pointer or functor

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, type-deduction

I'm trying to deduce the return type of a callable type, i.e. a function pointer or a functor.

I previously asked and got an answer showing how to do this for function pointers with hints for how to do this for functors.

[Function return type deduction in C++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080471/function-return-type-deduction-in-c03)

Based on that, I have this helper struct which now works for functors but no longer works for function pointers.

```
// functors
template<class T>
struct Return;
{
    typedef typename T::result_type type;
};

// function pointers
template<class R>
struct Return<R (*)()>
{
        typedef R type;
};
```

This works for cooperating functors that provide a `result_type` typedef but not for function pointers. clang gives the following:

> error: type 'int (*)(int)' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
>
> ```
> typedef typename T::result_type type;
> ```

I'm confused by why this isn't a SFINAE error that would move on and catch the specialization of `Return`.

You can try this yourself and also see some of the context to what I'm doing.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53f4c8c90787e329

**Context**

This builds on this question.

[“Overload” function template based on function object operator() signature in C++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324124/overload-function-template-based-on-function-object-operator-signature-in-c)

In that question I was trying to create a function template that will map a std::vector to a new std::vector by using a passed mapping function. Now I'm trying to map from a container that provides a means of iterating over its contents. In the answer to that question the function template had the form:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
typename expr_check<sizeof(declval<F>()(declval<T>())), std::vector<T> >::type
map_vec(F fnc, const std::vector<T>& source)
```

Where `F` is a callable type and `T` is both the type of the argument taken by type `F` and also parameterizes the return type, `std::vector<T>`. See the question for explanation of `declval`.

Now I want the function template to take a container type, call it `C`. My thinking is that T should be deduced as the return type of type `F` here and so is no longer a parameter itself. Right now I'm trying to get the template to work with this signature:

```
template<typename F, typename C>
typename expr_check<sizeof(declval<F>()(declval<int>())),
        std::vector<typename Return<F>::type> >::type
map_vec(F fnc, const C& source);
```

Comment: Your error is only specializing for exactly zero arguments. You want to specializze for arbitrary arguments.

Comment: I just realized that! That was really boneheaded and I gave up too easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is only specializing for exactly zero arguments.

As pre-C++11 does not have variadic templates, you will have to add one specialization for each count up to your limit.

If you can use C++11 features, just use [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Answer (score 2):

This was a silly mistake that Deduplicator caught.

The working example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdb79bbdeedfaa65

The problem was simply that there need to be specializations of `Return` appropriate for the function signatures that will be used.

```
// functors
template<class T>
struct Return
{
    typedef typename T::result_type type;
};

// function pointers
template<class R, class T>
struct Return<R (*)(T)>
{
        typedef R type;
};

// function pointers
template<class R, class T, class U>
struct Return<R (*)(T, U)>
{
        typedef R type;
};
```